# Proving that definite integral gives the area under the curve using the following definition.

Tags: proof-writing, area, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

[image]

Using this definition how do we prove that the area under the curve is given by the definite integral. The definition of integral I am using is the Riemann's definition.

*The definition which uses partitions and tags.*

Comment: Did you read Apostol  _Calculus_ Vol. 1 ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Well, no?

Comment: Riemann integral is not defined there as a limit of Riemann sums ....

Comment: @TonyPiccolo I am taking the Wikipedia definition, and that's what my question is.  Prove this using these definitions.

Comment: The source of wiki article is Apostol's. If you want to start from the definition that uses tagged partitions, you have to prove it implies the statement on step functions used by Apostol as a definition of integral. Then you can read the proof of Th. 1.10 to conclude.

Comment: You don't need to read Apostol: see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We are speaking of a non-negative function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ of course.

If $f$ is Riemann integrable, you can find upper and lower sums arbitrarily close to each other.

If you remember the geometrical meaning of upper and lower sums, you are done.

Comment: The geometrical meaning of the uppers and lower sums is the area of several rectangles summed up, and nothing else?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Upper and lower sums are areas of step regions. They are also called Darboux sums. Do you know Darboux integral ?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Consider the theorem _A Riemann integrable function is also Darboux integrable_. Its proof is what you need.